# Find Contours not accurate

Tags: python, opencv

I have a question to find the contours of this image I've used the findcontour is not very accurate am I doing wrong ?

[image: Here's my result but its not accurate.]

[image: Here's the image I've used]

```
gs = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gs, (3,3),0)
ret_otsu,im_bw_otsu = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = np.ones((50,50),np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(im_bw_otsu, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

plottedContour = cv2.drawContours(gs,contours,-1,(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imshow('CONTOUR',plottedContour)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might want to look at additional contours,

```
cv2.drawContours(gs,contours,-1,(0,255,0),2)
cv2.drawContours(gs,contours,0,(0,255,0),2)
cv2.drawContours(gs,contours,1,(0,255,0),2)
cv2.drawContours(gs,contours,2,(0,255,0),2)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to obtain a binary image the filter for the largest contour with the assumption that the banana is the main object in the image. From here we can draw a rectangle using [`cv2.rectangle`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle) or draw around the contour with [`cv2.drawContours`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#how-to-draw-the-contours). Optionally, we can also crop the ROI using Numpy slicing.

Drawn rectangle

[image]

Drawn contour

[image]

Extracted ROI

[image]

Code

```
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours and sort for largest contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

for c in cnts:
    # Crop ROI
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite('ROI.png', ROI)

    # Draw rectangle
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)

    # Draw contours
    # cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 2)
    break

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```